# MSBuild error MSB4018:: The "MultiToolTask" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, msbuild, clang

I am working on a Qt project on Visual Studio 2019 and I wanted to switch from MSVC to Clang. I installed clang-cl through the Visual Studio Installer and changed the *Platform Toolset* project setting to clang.

Now when I try to build my project I get the following error:
`MSB4018: The "MultiToolTask" task failed unexpectedly`.

I read on [this VS Developer Community issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/some-projects-wont-build-when-using-llvm-clang-cl/933174) that Qt projects won't compile with Clang if the Multi-processor Compilation (/MP) flag is set to 'Yes'.

So I tried setting it to 'No' and the projects builds successfully.
Now, the problem is that full build takes twice as much time as before. (10min vs 5min)

Is there a way to enable Multi-processor Compilation with Clang for Qt projects ?